# stargazer arima html dont't work

Tags: html, r, stargazer

I am trying to use the stargazer package to create a beautiful output in r. But I run into the problem that it works for `type = "latex"` , but not in `type = "html"`, throwing error `Error in column.matrix [r, i]: subscript out of bounds`. Any idea how to fix it.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: " "
date: "Sys.Date()"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
data("AirPassengers")
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(fit)
fit2 <- arima(AirPassengers, order = c(2,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,0))
stargazer(fit2, type = "latex")
stargazer(fit2, type = "html")
```
Error in column.matrix[r, i] : subscript out of bounds
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be a problem in your first chunk of code carrying over to the second, perhaps introduced by `library(forecast)` which may be overwriting something that `stargazer` needs for the table. Also, I know that `auto.arima` is not supported in stargazer, only the `stats::arima`. My RMarkdown chunk was:

````
```{r, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(stargazer)
fit2 <- stats::arima(AirPassengers, order = c(2,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,0))
stargazer(fit2, type = "html")
```
````

And it produced this HTML:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that `library(forecast)` is the problem. I solved this myself by only loading the `forecast` package _after_ exporting the `arima` model to `stargazer`.

Comment: This may be useful. When I load the `forecast` package, it says the following. Registered S3 method overwritten by `quantmod`: method `as.zoo.data.frame` from `zoo`. Attaching package: `forecast`. The following object is masked from package `astsa`: `gas`.